# Angular App - unable to get css file by link in browser

Tags: javascript, css, angular, docker

I run Angular application on Docker container.
Everything works fine.
But when I try to get css file content by url in my browser then app redirect me to dashboard of my application.

If I try to do the same with js or ts files then browser show me content of that files so it's correct.

Why I can't get content of css files?

http://localhost:4200/main.js - show contents = CORRECT

http://localhost:4200/style.css - don't show contents = INCORRECT

Do I need to set some params in angular config? Or I need to modify Dockrfile?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14

ARG API_URL=http://localhost:8080
ARG CLOUD_API_URL=http://localhost:8080
ARG APP_VERSION
ARG RECAPTCHA_KEY
ARG STRIPE_KEY
ARG MAPBOX_KEY

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm run start-dev"]
```

Thank you.

Comment: The Dockerfile seems fine, except for the `ARG` lines that leak credentials.  What inside your server code is supposed to serve these files?  Have you verified that the CSS file is in fact inside the image (do you need to run some sort of build step?).

Answer (score 0):

i think it doesn't have to be related to docker, the css files are compiled to `styles.css` where you are trying to access `style.css`.

for example iam running this test project on a docker instance and the contents that compiled are
[image]

so as per the bundle list i accessed http://localhost:4200/styles.css
and style file is showing correctly as below.
[image]

Hope this helps.